Styling an inset shadow of a text
I'm trying to implement an inset shadow of text with CSS, but I've only reached a solution with setting a special attribute to HTML tag.
I've searched for different solution on the net, but they have a problem with overflowing light shadow, here's an example:

Can I somehow get the element's inner text value and set the content property with this value? Or maybe there is different solution?
There is my solution with setting additional data-text attribute:


.inner-text-shadow {
    font-size: 10rem;
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;

    color: hsla(0, 0%, 13%, 1);
    
    position: relative;
}

.inner-text-shadow::after {
    content: attr(data-text);

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;

    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #FFF;
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
<h1 class="inner-text-shadow" data-text="Inset shadow">Inset shadow</h1>



So with this solution I get the desired result, but I don't like the idea of manually duplicating the element's text to the attribute.

You could have a JS function automate setting the data-text attribute and it would still be useable as a selector in CSS.



 .inner-text-shadow
                    {
                 font-size: 10rem;
                    color: hsla(0, 0%, 13%, 1);
                
                    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
                          text-shadow: 
                    1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8),
                    -1px -1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8),
                    1px -1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8),
                    -1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8),
                    2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
                    -2px -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
                    2px -2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
                    -2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            };
                    }
        <h1 class="inner-text-shadow">Inset shadow</h1>




In this method, the shadows appear outside the characters. I'm looking for a solution with only internal ones.

I have made some changes please check now

Please explain (inside the answer) how this would solve the issue
